# Outbound traffic in amazon ec2 instance not working

Tags: amazon-ec2

Outbound requests are not working in my instance.

When I give a wget a url https:

it happens

Solving www.facebook.com (www.facebook.com) ... 31.13.65.36, 2a03: 2880: f111: 83: face: b00c: 0: 25de

Connecting to www.facebook.com (www.facebook.com) | 31.13.65.36 |: 80 ... connected.

The HTTP request was sent, awaiting response ... 302 Found

Location: https://www.facebook.com/ [redirecting]

--2017-04-19 11: 32: 20-- https://www.facebook.com/

Connecting to www.facebook.com (www.facebook.com) | 31.13.65.36 |: 443 ...

And be like this forever... 
Already configured in the security group area for all traffics 0.0.0.0/0 and it still does not work.
In other instances it works perfectly

Comment: Does this happen *just* for Facebook.com?

Comment: for all https urls

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked:

1. The Outbound rules of the Security Group associated with the
   Instance?
2. The Outbound and Inbound rules of the Network ACL associated with the Subnet the Instance is on? Remember that NACLs are stateless so you have to add both inbound and outbound rules for the traffic.
3. The Route table associated with the Subnet the instance is on to make sure Internet traffic is being forwarded to the Internet Gateway

Comment: how i check te rules of network acl??